# Google Fusion Tables examples on Blogger

Tags: google-maps-api-3, blogger, google-fusion-tables

I am trying the fusion tables examples on my blogger blog but the maps do not show up.   It is pretty much a cut-and-paste of the example code except I use my own maps API code and my own fusion table ID. I enabled the fusion table API and did a query from my browser to confirm I can read all the data from the fusion table.

Basically I copy and paste the code right from here and it does not work so I think there is something with blogger

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-heatmap

First I tried taking that code and changing the query a bit along with my API key and fusion table ID, and when that did not work I just copy and paste that code verbatim into a "Page" in blogger and it does not work.

Any help out there?

Here is my code minus my table ID and my API key

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Fusion Tables heatmaps</title>
<style>
  /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
   * element that contains the map. */
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 47.22155, lng: -76.72791},
      zoom: 3
    });

    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
        select: 'geometry',
        from: 'FOO'
      },
    });

    layer.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=FOO&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a simple API program that I put in a different page on blogger and it works fine.  Very basic but no fusion tables.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
   #map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h3>La Verendrye</h3>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: 47.01837498778204, lng: -76.71812826048739};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
<script
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-API-CODE&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I have been doing more investigation and now remove my previous answer.  It is definitely something funny going on within blogger - blogger is interfering somehow.  I did some code comparisons between the simple working example without fusion tables, and the one with fusion tables.  I determined that my first problem was this template :

```
#map {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This was causing nothing to display.  If I change it to

```
#map {
    height: 720px;
}
```

Then I get my map showing with the fusion table datapoints, but now the issue is that no base layer is showing.  I google that issue and cannot find much.

Here are my two pages that you can compare.  Here is my blogger one :

http://www.prospector16.com/p/fusion-table-test.html

and now here is the exact same code but I went into my DNS for that domain and pointed the "aws" host at my Amazon AWS instance, and I put the exact same code in there and it works fine :

http://aws.prospector16.com/algonquin-campsites.html

In fact the working version even works fine without changing the "height: 100%" to "height: 720px".  It works fine with height of 100%

So this is clearly something going on with the blogger side of things.  Can someone help?